# what happens if the folders in c:\Users are set read only?

Tags: windows, domain

A computer with windows 10 is in a domain, a lot of users can log in using domain accounts.

What happens, if someone with local admin rights logs on, and sets all folders in C:/Users to "read only" including subfolders?

Can the domain users still log on afterwards? Are they force logged off because domain controller cannot write because read only?

Answer (score 2):

The user will get a temporary profile until the problem is resolved.

This effectively means that they can login, but they lose their settings for that session and have a clean desktop and no access to their files.

Keep in mind that the reason is not because the folder is set to read only, but because changing this means someone else has to change the ownership of a folder first which breaks the profile.

Do also note that you cannot actually use windows explorer to assign read-only rights to a folder. You need to open a command prompt as administrator and use the attrib command.

You can test this by creating a new folder and before doing anything, check its properties. You'll see the read-only filled with a square and you cannot change this by changing the read-only checkbox and pressing ok. The folder will go back to the square when you check it again. It will however change the read-only setting to all files in the folder.